# How to open my TopComponent in "explorer" mode?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am doing netBeans platform application.when I creating top component I give it as "explorer" mode to start.But in default it start in "editor" mode.Here the annotations which top component automatically generated.

```
@ConvertAsProperties(
        dtd = "-//MyApplication.windows//MyViewer//EN",
        autostore = false)
    @TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "MyViewerTopComponent",
        //iconBase="SET/PATH/TO/ICON/HERE", 
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS)
    @TopComponent.Registration(mode = "explorer", openAtStartup = true)
@ActionID(category = "Window", id = "MyApplication.windows.MyViewerTopComponent")
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window" /*, position = 333 */)
@TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration(
        displayName = "#CTL_MyViewerAction",
        preferredID = "MyViewerTopComponent")
    @Messages(
        {
    "CTL_MyViewerAction=MyViewer",
    "CTL_MyViewerTopComponent=MyViewer Window",
    "HINT_MyViewerTopComponent=This is a MyViewer window"
})
```

Please give me any suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Did you do any changes in layer.xml file ? That could be it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.  I unchecked a module dependency called RCP Platform and the windows would only open in editor position.  I was trying to find the minimum modules needed to run my program.

You can see which modules are used by right clicking the project node and choosing properties.  Look at libraries and expand the Platform node.  Make sure RCP Platform is checked.  If it gives an error, just click resolve.  Make sure you do a clean and build afterwords.

There is one easier thing you should check first.  When you run a NB platform program, it opens windows in the last used position.  If you moved a window, it will reopen where you last moved it to.  You have to do a clean and build to reset this.